# Linear Transformation Question Help

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

**Question:** Let $T: R^3$ -> $R^2$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(x)=Ax$ where
$$A =\begin{bmatrix}1 & -5 & -3\\-3&15&9\end{bmatrix}$$
If $\begin{bmatrix}2 \\b\end{bmatrix}$ is in the range of $T$, find the value of "b".

**My attemped solution:** I understand the basic concepts behind problems like this where $T(x)$ represents the range of $T$ and that $T(x)$ in $R^m$ is the image of $x$ under $T$. However, I'm not very sure how to solve this problem given that a vector with variable $b$ and we have to solve for the value(s) of b to see if it's in the range of $T$. Generally when I check if a column vector is in the range of $T$, I would put the column vector as the augumenting matrix for $A$ and row reduce the matrix to check if there are any correct solutions. But in this case it doesn't seem to work.

I'd much appreciate it if someone could show me how this is done. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note how the second row $\begin{bmatrix}-3&15&9\end{bmatrix}$ is a multiple of the first row $\begin{bmatrix}1&-5&-3\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: The second and third columns of $A$ are scalar multiplies of the first column. It's easy to see that $y=-3x$ is the image of $A$ which means $b=-3\cdot 2=-6$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}1&-5&-3\\-3&15&9\end{bmatrix} \mathbf x &= \begin{bmatrix}2\\b\end{bmatrix}\\
\begin{bmatrix}1&-5&-3\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} \mathbf x &= \begin{bmatrix}2\\b+6\end{bmatrix} & R_2 \to R_2+3R_1
\end{align*}$$

If the matrix equation is consistent, then $b+6 = 0$, so $b = -6$.

---

For completeness, there are some $\mathbf x$s that satisfy $A\mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix}2\\-6\end{bmatrix}$, e.g. for $y,z\in\mathbb R$,

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbf x &= \begin{bmatrix}2+5y+3z\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} + y \begin{bmatrix}5\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

The question is: if $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2\\b\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is of the form $A.\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ for some vector $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, then what is $b$? Note that$$A.\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x-5y-3z\\-3x+15y+9z\end{bmatrix}.\tag1$$Clearly, there are vectors of the form $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2\\b\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ in the range of $T$; take $x=2$ and $y=z=0$, for instance. But the second line of the RHS of $(1)$ is the first one time $-3$. So, the only $b$ such that $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2\\b\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is in the range is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2\\-6\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, that is, $b$ must be $-6$.